# Why is my useEffect hook updating too late?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to have an image and text update when I click a button, which it does, but the image is from the previous state. Is there a way to have it so that it changes instantly? Any help is appreciated. Using React btw.

```
function Footer({ spotify }) {
    const [{ item, playing }, dispatch] = useDataLayerValue();

    useEffect(() => {
        spotify.getMyCurrentPlaybackState().then((r) => {
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_PLAYING",
                playing: r.is_playing,
            });
    
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_ITEM",
                item: r.item,
            });
        });
    }, [spotify]);
    
    const handlePlayPause = () => {
        if (playing) {
            spotify.pause();
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_PLAYING",
                playing: false,
            });
        } else {
            spotify.play();
            dispatch({
                type: "SET_PLAYING",
                playing: true,
            });
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className='footer'>
            <div className="footer__left">
                <img className="footer__albumLogo"
                    src={item?.album.images[0].url}
                    alt={item?.name}
                    key={item?.album.images[0].url}/>
                {item ? (
                    <div className="footer__songInfo">
                        <h4>{item.name}</h4>
                        <p>{item.artists.map((artist) => artist.name).join(", ")}</p>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className="footer__songInfo">
                        <h4>No song is playing</h4>
                        <p>...</p>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
// NEW EDIT
            <div className="footer__center">
                <ShuffleIcon className="footer__green" />
                <SkipPreviousIcon className="footer__icon" />
                {playing ? (
                    <PauseCircleOutlineIcon
                        onClick={handlePlayPause}
                        fontSize="large"
                        className="footer__icon"
                    />
                ) : (
                    <PlayCircleOutlineIcon
                        onClick={handlePlayPause}
                        fontSize="large"
                        className="footer__icon"
                    />
                )}
                <SkipNextIcon className="footer__icon" />
                <RepeatIcon className="footer__green" />
             </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

I think that the issue is within the "div className="footer__left"" but it may be an entirely different issue.

Comment: Where is the button that is updating the state?

Comment: I have just edited it to show the button at //NEW EDIT

Comment: The button you provided updates the `playing` value of your state, but it sounds like the issue is with behavior that affects the `item` value of the state